# Uploading files, adding to database and showing to user

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to upload a file, save it to a database and then show the user his uploaded file.
Here's the database for the **Image Files**.

```
Field    Type         NULL   DeFault
ID        int          NO
PIC       varchar(255) NO
```

Here's the **HTML** for uploading the file.

```
<form method="post" action="addMember.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p>
              Photo:
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
            <input type="file" name="photo"> 

            <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" value="Add Picture"/>
          </form>
```

Here's the back php file :-

```
<?php
 include 'dbconnector.php';

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "/img";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form

$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);


// Connects to your Database


//Writes the information to the database
$query="INSERT into testImage VALUES(NULL, '" . $pic . "')";
$result=mysql_query($query,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

The **problem** is, that the files aren't getting uploaded to the **img** directory.
What's wrong in the code ?

Also, how should I write the code to **display** the same file to a user?
Thanks.

P.S - I've plucked the code from one of the stackoverflow pages and edited it.

---

UPDATE :- I now see that all the files are now uploaded in the root **/** directory. The image file is like this **img** (the directory name I mentioned as target in the code), and then the uploaded file name.
Why it isn't going in the /img directory.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: is the directory writable?

Comment: @JohnConde
Not much troubleshooting actually. I changed the directory, changed the path, but nothing works.
Nouphal.M - Yes, the directory is writable.

Comment: What is the value of $target in move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're missing a / between the directory and file name. It should be $target = $target .'/'. basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

Comment: I meant the value of the $target variable, see my comment above for what i'm getting at ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're missing a / between the directory and file name. It should be:

```
$target = $target .'/'. basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
```

Comment: Thankyou, this worked.
How can I display the picture from the database itself?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing directory separator in your `$target`. You can see the problem when you echo the variable.

```
$target = $target . "/" . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
```

Use this to display the picture:

```
//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

   //Tells you if its all ok
   echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
   // print the image
   echo '<img src="' . $target . '" alt="uploaded image" />';
}
```

Edit:

Fetch image from database:

```
// connect to database

$query = mysql_query('SELECT pic FROM testImage WHERE id = 1;',$db) or die (mysql_error($db));

$image = mysql_result($result, 0);
echo "<img src=\"/img/$image\" alt=\"uploaded image\" />";
```

Comment: Thankyou, this worked.
But the displaying part didn't work, plus, I need to fetch the files from the database.
How can I do that?

Comment: You can fetch them like my new example.